# Return a jquery object from MVC Controller to jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to make a call to an ASP.NET MVC Controller and have it return a jquery object to jquery method under cshtm[image]l page,

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please, next time just add code, not screenshot of code.

Comment: Not next time, please edit your question to do it here. It's incredibly hard to read the screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

change object result to var result and return it with in try scope

Comment: I want to return Jquery object from controller only. I don't want to change object result

Comment: Doesn't matter. Even if you return normal list of button type it will be converted to json

Comment: how can pass button Type from controller? do u have any idea?

Comment: Make class name buttonjquery and define  priperties like you have in your pic. And create list<button> btn  return it to json

Comment: I think you sre saying, I have create a button class in code behind and use it. How can I send jquery button name to js method under cshtml page? It's  again string (name), when I fetch string value under JS method, It's showing with double quotes.

Comment: you can not use json string to use as buttonname.
try to use partialview